# Problems with continue in foreach loop

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php
function recursive($directory){
    $nr = 0;
    $files = scandir($directory);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
        if(is_dir($file)){
            echo $file.'<br>';
            continue;
        }
        echo $file.' ----------<br>';

    }
}
recursive('.');
?>
```

Basically I want the code at the bottom of the loop to be skipped until they are no more files in the directory.

How I want it to look:

> [image]

How it looks:

> [image]

Comment: Are you sure that how you want it to look. It does not mean much like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you first need to list the directories, then the files. You can do that by changing a bit your function and running it twice:

```
function recursive($directory, $type){
    $nr = 0;
    $files = scandir($directory);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
        if(is_dir($file) && $type == 'dir'){
            echo $file.'<br>';
        } else if(!is_dir($file) && $type == 'file'){
            echo $file.' ----------<br>';
        }
    }
}
recursive('.', 'dir');
recursive('.', 'file');
```

(By the way, although it's called "recursive", it doesn't do recursion)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot! And I will change its name haha

Comment: For the question I cut out all the non-vital code (i.e. the recursive part).

Answer (score 2):

A different take on your code but have you looked at the `recursiveIterator` family of classes? It's part of the php core and is pretty powerful.

```
        $folder='c:/temp';
        foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $folder, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $file => $info ) {
            if( $info->isFile() && $info->isReadable() && $info->isWritable() ){
                echo $info->getFilename().'-------<br />';
            } elseif( $info->isDir() ){
                echo $info->getPath().'<br />';
            }
        }
```

Comment: I did but I need more experience to be able to use it, that sounded like an MMORPG lol :) Thanks!

Comment: With this code, the directories and files won't be in the correct order (dir should come first, then files)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
echo $file.'<br>';
if(is_dir($file) === false){
    echo $file.' ----------<br>';            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't seem to work, however it is resolved!